# Protected Majorana Zero modes in Kitaev Chain

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity

Kitaev's one-dimensional p-wave superconductor Hamiltonian${}^\dagger$ is
\begin{equation}
    {\cal H}_{JW}=-J\sum\limits_i(c_{i}^\dagger c_{i+1} + c_{i+1}^\dagger c_{i} + c_{i}^\dagger c_{i+1}^\dagger + c_{i+1} c_{i} - 2gc_{i}^\dagger c_{i}+g)
\end{equation}

After Fourier transformation ($c_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum\limits_j c_je^{ikx_j}$) hamiltonian becomes
\begin{equation}\label{afterfourier}
{\cal H}_f= \sum\limits_k(2[Jg-J\cos(ka)]c_{k}^\dagger c_{k}+iJ\sin(ka)[c_{-k}^\dagger c_{k}^\dagger + c_{-k}c_{k}]-Jg)
\end{equation}

If I am not wrong, by ignoring constant term, above Hamiltonian can also be written in standard Bogoliubov-de Gennes form
\begin{equation}\label{bdgequation}
{\cal H}_{BdG} = J\sum\limits_k\Psi_k^\dagger \begin{pmatrix}g-\cos k & -i \sin k\\ i\sin k & -g+\cos k \end{pmatrix}\Psi_k 
\end{equation}

where
$$\Psi_k = \begin{pmatrix}
           c_{-k}\\
           c_k^\dagger
           \end{pmatrix}
$$

The energy spectrum for particle-hole symmetry is symmetric about zero. For hole, it is $-\epsilon_k/2$ and for electron it is $\epsilon_k/2$. Where
$$\epsilon_k=2J\sqrt{1+g^2-2g\cos(ka)}$$

If we do Bogoliubov transformation of Fourier transformed Hamiltonian, we get

\begin{equation}\label{eq:BVtrans}
 {\cal H}=\sum\limits_k\epsilon_k(\gamma_k^\dagger \gamma_k-1/2)
\end{equation}

**My Question**

- How particle-hole symmetric Hamiltonian is protecting the Majorana-zero-mode in one phase.

${}^\dagger$In special case when $t=\Delta$

Comment: This has been explained many times. E.g., take a look at section II.A in Jason Alicea's review paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.1293

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particle-hole energy spectrum is symmetric around zero energy.

[image]

When $g\to 0$, we have two zero energy levels, corresponding to the Majorana zero modes which are localized far away from each other and separated by a gaped medium. It is not possible to move these levels from zero energy individually (as one needs to respect particle-hole symmetry). The only way to split the Majorana modes in energy is to first close the bulk energy gap. For more refer [this.](https://topocondmat.org/w1_topointro/1D.html)